# Is the derivative an approximation? (Cost function, marginal cost, deviation in costs)

Tags: functions, derivatives, intuition

Good evening everyone,

I wonder if the derivative is an approximation.

Because if I am calculating marginal costs there is always some small deviations regarding the marginal cost (additional cost in the case of producing one quantity more).

e.g.:
Let the cost function be
$C(x)=x^2+5x$ with $x$ denoting the quantity.

The derivative (here marginal cost function) in respect to $x$ is:

$C'(x) = 2x+5$.

Now for $C=1; C=2$ we get:

$C(1)=6$

$C(2)=14$

The Derivatives at $C=1;C=2$ are

$C'(1)=7$

$C'(2)=9$

So the change from (incurring costs in the case that we produce one quantity more) $C(1)$ to $C(2)$ is $8$.

But why is the derivative at position $C'(1)$ then 7 and not $8$ ?

It seems like the derivative is an approximation and not really "exact" because there is always a difference of 1 regarding $C(x+1)-C(x)$.

Hope someone can clearify this, because in the case of other functions ($3x^2+4$) the difference varies (in the case of $3x^2+4$ the difference is always 3).

It is that $C(x+1)-C(x)$ is the exact difference in costs whereby the derivative has always an deviation/error.

sincerely,
Monoid

Comment: $C(x+1)-C(x)$ is the derivative at some point between $x$ and $x+1$ (and this the best that you can say in general, that is, for an arbitrary function).

Comment: @Monoid it's really more the other way around, taking the difference between two costs with close x values is an approximation of the derivative. The derivative is the difference in the function as the difference in x goes to zero. Looking at it from your perspective, adding the derivative to the function to get to the next value is just doing a truncated version of the Taylor series.

Comment: A derivative of a function is NOT an approximation. It has different menaings depending on the nature of the function. First derivative of the cost function is the Marginal Cost. There is a good explanation of derivatives as it relates to Cost Function in here https://www.dummies.com/education/math/calculus/how-to-determine-marginal-cost-marginal-revenue-and-marginal-profit-in-economics/ and here:http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/calc_econ_interp_u.html

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is actually by definition a limit. The reason that your intuition tells you that $C'(1)$ should be $8$ is because that is the *slope* of the secant line connecting $C(7)$ and $C(8). The purple line below might help you picture what this looks like intuitively. [image]

The green line represents the derivative "slope" at $x=1$, and the red line represents the slope of the line connecting the two points. Notice that it's not as steep as the red line.